# C# Iterate Over DataGridView & Change Row Color

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, row, loops

I have a datagridview made up of multiple rows and columns.
I want to iterate through each row and check the contents of a specific column. 
If that column contains the word "NO", I want to change the forecolor of the entire row to Red.
Here is an attempt at some code so far but It's certainly not working, starting to wonder If I need to iterate over every cell?

CODE:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvr in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (dgvr.Cells["FollowedUp"].Value.ToString() == ("No"))
            {
                dgvr.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is "not working"? No rows? cell can't be found?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public void ColourChange()
    {
        DataGridViewCellStyle RedCellStyle = null;
        RedCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
        RedCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        DataGridViewCellStyle GreenCellStyle = null;
        GreenCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
        GreenCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Green;


        foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvr in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (dgvr.Cells["FollowedUp"].Value.ToString().Contains("No"))
            {
                dgvr.DefaultCellStyle = RedCellStyle;
            }
            if (dgvr.Cells["FollowedUp"].Value.ToString().Contains("Yes"))
            {
                dgvr.DefaultCellStyle = GreenCellStyle;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't gain anything by doing [Type x = null; x = new  Type();].  You should be merging those two lines into [Type x = new Type();]

Answer (score 26):

hook up **OnRowDataBound** event then do stuff

ASPX (Grid):

```
    <asp:.... OnRowDataBound="RowDataBound"..../>
```

Code Behind:

```
    protected void RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowIndex == -1)
        {
            return;
        }

        if(e.Row.Cells[YOUR_COLUMN_INDEX].Text=="NO"){
             e.Row.BackColor=Color.Red;   
        }
    }
```

FOR WinForms:

```
hook the **DataBindingComplete** event and do stuff in it:

     private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, 
                       DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ListChangedType != ListChangedType.ItemDeleted)
        {
            DataGridViewCellStyle red = dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.Clone();
            red.BackColor=Color.Red;

            foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (r.Cells["FollowedUp"].Value.ToString()
                       .ToUpper().Contains("NO"))
                {
                    r.DefaultCellStyle = red;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: oops! everything is so web and I'm myself deep in web project since 3 months that it seems normal that every question is about asp.net

Comment: Wasn't me, but my guess would be because it isn't relevant to the question? (i.e. question is tagged with Winforms) :-/

Answer (score 9):

On your DataGridView, handle the CellFormatting event:

```
dataGridView1.CellFormatting += new DataGridViewCellFormattingEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellFormatting);
```

Your event handler could then look like this:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{       
    if(dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "FollowedUp" && e.Value != null && e.Value.ToString() == "No")
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;  
}
```

In this way you aren't 'iterating' over the rows -- simply changing the color with which they are painted/drawn when they become visible (and thus require formatting) in the grid.

Comment: This method is a LOT slower, but the formatting doesn't get wiped out by a column header click sort.

Comment: Sorry, there was something wrong with my event handler code substitution and I can't edit my previous comment.  I would replace 'a LOT' with 'somewhat' slower.

Comment: Depending on what you're doing in the handler is going to make most of that (performance) determination. Ultimately though, using the handler method means that (as you say) it won't get wiped by column sorting. But also that in the case of a grid with thousands of rows you aren't "formatting" rows that the user may never see anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible there are spaces or some other character as part of the cell value?  If so try using the Contains method rather than straight equality.

```
if (dgvr.Cells["FollowedUp"].Value.ToString().Contains("No"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for Winforms:

```
private void HighlightRows()
{
    DataGridViewCellStyle GreenStyle = null;

    if (this.dgridv.DataSource != null)
    {
        RedCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
        RedCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;

        for (Int32 i = 0; i < this.dgridv.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (((DataTable)this.dgridv.DataSource).Rows[i]["col_name"].ToString().ToUpper() == "NO")
            {
                this.dgridv.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle = RedCellStyle;
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No Exception and No color changed. I dont know why please need help

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine for me:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if ((string)row.Cells["property_name"].Value == UNKNOWN_PROPERTY_NAME)
    {
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon;
        row.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Salmon;
    }
}
```

Other than casting as a string rather than calling ToString I dont really see any difference so it could be a case sensitivity bug. Try using:

```
dgvr.Cells["FollowedUp"].Value.ToString().ToUpper() == "NO"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Grd_Cust_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    colorCode == 4 ? Color.Yellow : Color.Brown;
    if (e.RowIndex < 0 || Grd_Cust.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["FollowedUp"].Value == DBNull.Value)
        return;
    string colorCode = Grd_Cust.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["FollowedUp"].Value.ToString();
    e.CellStyle.BackColor = colorCode == "NO" ? Color.Red : Grd_Cust.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Tip, you can use the `{}` button to format your code snippets.