# C#/.NET how to highlight certain rows in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, datasource

I have a [DataGridView](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datagridview-tutorial) that is filled by setting its [DataSource](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datasource) to a DataBinding.

Now I want to have certain rows in the DataGridView having different Backgroundcolor according to some value in the row itself.

How can I possibly accomplish this?

Comment: I think you can find some useful info from this question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078782/c-iterate-over-datagridview-change-row-color

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a great example [here.](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/7/10063891/how-to-customize-data-fo.aspx)

The concept is that you subscribe to events from the grid. When a cell is filled, an event is fired and based upon the value you can format the cell etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the RowPrePaint to change the color or style of the whole row

Answer (score 1):

In the CellFormatting event handler of your datagridview you can set the default backcolor for any row you want.

```
private void MyDataGridView_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.RowIndex == rowIndexToHighlight)
        {
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
        }

    }
```

Comment: -1 because this example has really poor performance implications.  If using databinding then the data grid will need to maintain duplicate row records.  Psasik's example avoids un-sharing rows.

Comment: @Kleinux: That is an interesting comment about maintaining duplicate row records. Could you explain why this is so? Thanks

Comment: If you look in the docs you will there is mention of shared vs unshared rows.  The code above forces the grid view to make actual DataGridViewRow records for every row in your data source.  These rows are not duplicates in the sense of the cell values, it can still read the data source for that, but they would otherwise not have to exists because of the now required style info.  Hopefully I have made my comment a little clearer.  This is a good tutorial http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ha5xt0d9.aspx

Comment: Fair enough, I changed my example.