# How to set the back color of the row / column header cell in a datagridview - c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, colors

I want to set the back color of the row header and column header intersection cell of a datagridview. I tried the below code, but it throws an exception that the number should be non negative.

```
DataGridViewCell cell = dgview.Rows[-1].Cells[-1];
cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

I want to set the color as shown in the image below

[image]

I also refered the below article, but it shows how to set the color of the whole column header. But my requirement is to set the color of a single cell - row-column header intersection cell.

[how-to-change-the-color-of-winform-datagridview-header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247800/how-to-change-the-color-of-winform-datagridview-header)

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Regards,

Vinay

Comment: It's not that odd that you get that exception. The index cannot be negative

Comment: Thanks Oskar. I understand that the exception is fine. But how do I achieve my goal? I'm trying all crooks to do it. :)

Comment: I don't really know. I'm guessing the easiest way (Which I've done before) is to just make your own paint method

Comment: I haven't tried this but try overlapping it with an absolutely placed graphics object. I'll give it a whirl and let you know the details.

Comment: I don't usually work with WCF, so I'm asking this - is the first column (index 0) the first column that contains data or the one where your cell is located?

Comment: Hi Michael Dmitry, index 0 is the first column which contains the actual data. Please let me know if this answers your question. Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at the following link hope this help.

[C# Iterate Over DataGridView & Change Row Color][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078782/c-iterate-over-datagridview-change-row-color/1078875#1078875

Comment: Have a look at the following link hope this help.

[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078782/c-iterate-over-datagridview-change-row-color/1078875#1078875

Comment: @Michael first of all, WCF is Windows Communication Foundation, you are think of WPF which is Windows Presentation Foundation. This is neither, this is Windows Forms

Comment: @S.Amani, thanks for the link, but it shows how to change the color of the whole column header. The requirement is to change the color of a single cell and not the whole header. thanks much.

Comment: Vinay, thanks. Then I have no idea what to do here.

@Oskar, yeah, sorry, I'm a bit tired. A slip of the keyboard.

Comment: Hey Guys, as usual, thanks much for all your help and support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store the current ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle  in a variable.

Set the ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle to how you want the corner to be.

Then change all of the columns headers to how you want columns 0 to ... back to the old style.

Below is an example where the form is called "MyForm".  This example shows the default constructor of MyForm.

Example:

```
    public MyForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // insert code here to add columns  ...
        // ...
        // ...
        // ...

        DataGridViewCellStyle oldDefault = dgview.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Clone();

        dgview.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;

        foreach (DataGridViewColumn item in dgview.Columns)
        {
            item.HeaderCell.Style = oldDefault;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Jason, you can remove "In other words you can no longer rely on the defaultcellstyle" from your post, as the new method holds the old cell style and restores it. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex == -1 && e.ColumnIndex ==  -1)

        {
            using (Brush gridBrush = new SolidBrush(this.dataGridView1.GridColor))
            {
                using (Brush backColorBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red))
                {
                    using (Pen gridLinePen = new Pen(gridBrush))
                    {
                        // Clear cell 
                        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(backColorBrush, e.CellBounds);
                        //Bottom line drawing
                        e.Graphics.DrawLine(gridLinePen, e.CellBounds.Left, e.CellBounds.Bottom-1 , e.CellBounds.Right, e.CellBounds.Bottom-1);
                        e.Handled = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi DSW, thanks for the link. However this link provides information about changing the styles (including color) of complete row and column headers. My requirement is to change the color of a single cell whose row and column index is -1.

Comment: Updated my answer, you can use `CellPainting` event

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hack, but add a PictureBox inside the DataGridView using the designer(if you're using VS) and initialize it's properties such as:

```
pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;
pictureBox1.Width = dgView.RowHeadersWidth;
pictureBox1.Height = dgView.ColumnHeadersHeight;
```

Comment: hi arviman, this did not work. The color remains the same. No change.

Comment: The designer generated code should give the same Location coordinates for both the picture box and the DataGridView. Also, the order of adding the controls in the designer's code should be `this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1);
this.Controls.Add(this.dgView);`